# Delphi dll and c# pinvoke declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, delphi, pinvoke

I am wondering if someone could check my c# dllimport declaration for a dll compiled with Delphi XE2. Calling this dll from a ISAPI wrapper dll works fine but I am having no luck calling it from a c# asp.net app.

The Delphi procedure is defined as:

```
procedure ExecuteService(const RequestJSON :PWideChar; out ResponseJSON :Pointer; out ResponseJSONSize :Integer; out ResponseContent :Pointer; out ResponseContentSize :Integer); stdcall;
```

and the c# declaration is:

```
 [DllImport("services.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern void BIExecuteService(
            String requestJSON,
            out IntPtr reposnseJSON,
            out int reposnseJSONSize,
            out IntPtr reposnseContent,
            out int reposnseContentSize
        );
```

Sometimes it works but mostly it gives a System.AccessViolationException.

I have been trying to solve this for days, do the declarations look correct?

**Edit:** Attaching to the IISExpress process in Delphi XE2 the error seems to occur in clr.dll. Maybe my library is corrupting something but I have no idea how to find out where!

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: Problem liable to be in how you call the function. You didn't show that. Ideally, you would show both Delphi and C# calling code. As asked, the question is trivial to answer, and the answer is probably of no use to you. This is a classic example of the XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your p/invoke declaration is correct. Your problems lie elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, so in general what would cause a system.accessviolation exception?

Comment: Specifically an AV is caused by an attempt to access an address which is either not mapped into your address space, or has incompatible protection level. Former is typically accessing stale pointer. Latter less common, arises when you try to write to read only memory.

Comment: You need to do some debugging. Make a reliable reproduction, and cut it down until you find out which code produces the AV.

Comment: I have tried to do this but I don't get consistent findings. Also it seems to be a timing issue and also depends on the number of simultaneous requests. It is incredibly frustrating! Would using a memory manager such as fastmm help? Also sometimes I don't even get an exception, IISExpress just crashes. Strangely on a colleagues PC it all works fine. On mine it doesn't work from IISEXpress in VS2012 or with the full blown IIS.

Comment: FastMM full debug might well help.